# How do i use folderbrowserdialog?

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

How do i use folderbrowserdialog ?

I want the user to be able to select any directory he want.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                DialogResult result1;
                result1 = new DialogResult();
                folderBrowserDialog1. = "Select New Folder To Collect Files";
                if (result1 == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

How can i do it ?

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear - it talks about a checkbox, but we have no idea what checkbox that is. Your code talks about "the problem with timer1" but doesn't explain what the problem is or what the fix is. You refer to `folderBrowserDialog1` once, in an invalid way - and then refer to `openFileDialog1` for the rest of the time. At no point are you *showing* either of these dialogs. Your question refers to `contentDirectory` but you never show that in the code. You have two empty `else` statements and one empty `if` statement... it's all very confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
using (FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string path = dialog.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
  if (result == DialogResult.OK) 
   {
    // Test result.
   }
```